# Cannot clone Git repository from remote due to a "curl 56 failure"?

Tags: git

I am unable to clone a repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/OSVVM/OSVVM

Cloning into 'OSVVM'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 91, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (91/91), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (63/63), done.
remote: Total 746 (delta 53), reused 66 (delta 28), pack-reused 655
Receiving objects: 100% (746/746), 18.04 MiB | 2.54 MiB/s, done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 Failure when receiving data from the peer
Resolving deltas: 100% (402/402), done.
```

Where can I find out more about this  "RPC failed; curl 56 Failure when receiving data from the peer"?

Comment: What OS, OS version, and Git version are you using?  Are you using a third-party firewall or antivirus, or is there a proxy or MITM SSL device on your network?

Comment: There is a proxy yes, but it does not stop other things from being downloaded. Is there  way to specify a security certificate to Git?

Comment: If you're asking about a TLS client certificate, then yes.  That would be `http.sslCert` and `http.sslKey`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely due to your use of a proxy.  There are known to be various issues with many proxies, especially filtering proxies, including failure to speak the protocol properly (including chunked transfer encoding, which Git uses extensively), inability to handle large payloads, modification or other tampering of the data, and all sorts of other infelicities.  Other things may work because they are not as large, because they have a known Content-Length, or because the data stream doesn't by happenstance contain some bad word or other magic pattern; that doesn't mean your proxy isn't broken.

Your best bet is to completely uninstall any third-party antivirus or firewall tools if you're on Windows and to avoid using any proxy or SSL/TLS MITM device, changing networks if necessary, in which case things will probably just work.  If you can't do that, then you should generate an SSH key pair and use SSH instead, because most proxies don't intercept that.

If you're in a corporate environment, you should also provide feedback to your network team that their proxy is misconfigured and broken so that they can fix it.

Comment: Yup, this is a common problem that affects many such environments, and Git just happens to be pretty intolerant to tampering (since it uses cryptography) and very good at triggering it.  You are far from the only person who has this class of problem.

Comment: Apprently, if I clear all the things under Windows Credentials inside the Credential Manager, I don't get that error anymore. How strange is that?

Answer (score 1):

Update the http post buffer value and try

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000
```

Comment: `http.postBuffer` affects _writing_ to the remote repo. We are talking about cloning here - that involves _reading_ big chunks from the remote repo. Increasing the postBuffer does not help here.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve the same problem by executing the below command in cmd prompt.

```
git config --global http.sslBackend openssl
```

Comment: This problem came and went intermittently. I am not even sure why it happened actually. Anyway, at work, I could never access Pypi reliably. It would work only occasionally and then stop and I would have to submit IT ticket every few weeks. I could goto Pypi on web browser but that would not download the dependancies. Eventually, I first downloaded the package and dependancies using pip on my PC, zip and email them to work email. Download them onto work machine and then store them on the corporate bitbucket account. This was the only way to be able to get work done.